# Blocking some websites in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp

Is there any way to block some websites in Windows XP without using any additional tools?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to block websites, and not use the internal Firewall, edit `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`, and give the named host the IP 0.0.0.0!

Comment: I did the process like this.. 127.0.0.1   facebook.com. But it didnt work.

Comment: www.facebook.com ? Ensure you don't have web proxies enabled, or do the same on your proxy server.

Comment: Just remember, www.facebook.com and facebook.com will both need to be entered.